# Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

the contact form this with the following error:

> Variable passed to each() is not an array or object

but the email comes in white, without it, without name and without the recipient of the email, what could be wrong?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Enviando email pelo PHP Através de um  formulário</title>
  </head>

<body>

<form action="formulario.php" method="POST">
  Seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome"><br> 
  Seu e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br> 
  Comentários: <textarea name="comentarios"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

formulario.php

```
<?PHP
// Set the message that will be sent to your e- mail below:
$mensagem = "Mensagem enviada em ".date("d/m/Y").", os dados seguem abaixo:\n"; 

// This loop puts all the form fields in the e- mail message to be sent
while(list($campo, $valor) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) { 
$mensagem .= ucwords($campo).": ".$valor."\n";
} 
 // Now we will make PHP send the form data to your email :
mail("teste@pauloroberto.xyz", "Assunto do E-mail", $mensagem, "From: $REMOTE_ADDR"); 

echo "Seu e-mail foi enviado com sucesso. Obrigado"; 
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, use `$_POST` in place of `$HTTP_POST_VARS.

Comment: that isn't phpmailer btw, it's php `mail()`. Two different animals here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated and no longer supported. Use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` instead...